# Why is InterfaceInterceptor not faster than TransparentProxyInterceptor?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a simple interface and its implementation:

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    long Sum(int ceiling);
}

public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public long Sum(int ceiling)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for (long i = 1; i <= ceiling; i++)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Call handler to measure calculating time:

```
public class MyCallHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        var result = getNext()(input, getNext);

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Trace.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks, "Benchmark");

        return result;
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Unity container is setup as follows:

```
IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.RegisterType<ICalculator, Calculator>();

unityContainer.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
unityContainer.Configure<Interception>().AddPolicy("MyPolicy")
    .AddMatchingRule(new MemberNameMatchingRule("Sum"))
    .AddCallHandler<MyCallHandler>();

unityContainer.Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor<ICalculator>(new TransparentProxyInterceptor());
```

When I call `unityContainer.Resolve<ICalculator>().Sum(80000)` I get ~2100 ticks for TransparentProxyInterceptor, and ~5500 ticks for InterfaceInterceptor.
When sum of millions is calculated, interceptors have almost the same performance, although MSDN specifically [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660861%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#interception_comparison) that InterfaceInterceptor is much faster than the TransparentProxyInterceptor.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to measure the times outside your call handler right before and after you call `Sum()`. Apart from that: 10.000 ticks are 1ms. I would not expect accurate measurements for such short periods of time.

Comment: Measuring total time leads to the same results

Comment: @SkyFx What about larger numbers? Or calls to multiple instances? InterfaceInterceptor generates IL code as far as I know. That might have an impact the first time you create an instance that gets intercepted.

Comment: I tried using large numbers and multiple calls. Still the same performance.